# How to create a loop for each different row based on a cell in sql-server?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables, assume `MIDS` and `TIDS.` Each row on `MIDS` has 1-many rows on `TIDS`. The number of rows on `TIDS`, it described by a cell on `MIDS` called `NumOfRows`.

I want to create as much records on `TIDS` as `NumOFRows` value and for each row on `MIDS`. i.e. `MIDS` has 2 rows, each row's `NumOfRows` value is `2` and `3` respectivly. So totally in `MIDS` will be created 6 rows, 2 for first row and 3 for the second row of `MIDS` table. 2 loops totally.

Any help on that?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: and please make up your mind regarding the platform: mySql or SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

An example and results that i'm expecting

'MIDS' 
Row 1:
'id':1 , 'NumOfTerminals': 2
Row 2:
'id':2 , 'NumOfTerminals': 3

'TIDS' 5 rows total
Row 1-2:
'id':1 , 'MIDS_ID': 1 
'id':2 , 'MIDS_ID': 1

Row 3-5:
'id':3 , 'MIDS_ID': 2
'id':4 , 'MIDS_ID': 2
'id':5 , 'MIDS_ID': 2

I hope i helped you.